# How do I get Sync Center working?

Tags: windows, sync

I'd like to sync a laptop with my desktop (both Winows 7) using Windows Sync Center. On the laptop, I can browse through the network to the desktop. If I right-click on a file on the desktop, the "Always available offline" option is missing. Additionally, if I open Sync Center, the lower pane that usually shows a list of sync partnerships says "There are no new sync partnerships that can be set up on this computer."

The opposite direction works just fine; I can set up a sync partnership from the desktop to the laptop. However, I need it to work the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably already learned this, but: "The ability to sync with network folders is not included in Windows Vista Starter, Windows Vista Home Basic, and Windows Vista Home Premium."

Could this be your problem?